# Tor browser further anonymity requirements

Tags: web-browser, tor

Tor and Tor Browser do a good job of providing anonymity, but we cannot rely on them alone.

The development of newer techniques for identifying web users (such as canvas fingerprinting) mean that using Tor or its browser alone are not enough to provide useful anonymity, or prevent tracking across the internet. For this reason, I was trying to understand the most important things to further ensure anonymity when using Tor/Tor Browser, and these are the two most important ones I came up with.

- Change the size of the browser each time (preventing the canvas fingerprinting identifying you by eg, your screensize)
- Never log in to a personalised service (eg email, obviously identifying)

I must have missed other important items. I want to know what else is important to know about, and why?

NOTE: I do not see how my question is at all a duplicate of another question which is specifically about Tor, and how Tor can be trusted. One is about a browser, and preventing being tracked against browser identifying techniques, the other is about Tor generally. Clearly no similarity.

Comment: Read [Technical analysis of client identification mechanisms](https://www.chromium.org/Home/chromium-security/client-identification-mechanisms) for a huge but still incomplete list of methods how the client can be tracked. Once you've read this your list of things to do will probably be much longer.

Comment: The Tor browser is protected against canvas fingerprinting.

Comment: @YdobEmos do you have a source for that claim?

Comment: @schroeder I get a warning every time a site tries to use canvas fingerprinting. Maybe I'm wrong, but you can try.

Comment: Use the default screen size so you blend in with others.

Answer (score -4):

Use a VPN at all times. It wouldn't hurt knowing your ISP doesn't know you are using TOR. Also make sure the VPN doesn't store or make logs.
Stay away from anything such as CP.
Don't use services like Google Maps on TOR. And of course don't enter any addresses around where you live on any search engines.

Comment: just one thing, what is cp?

Comment: A VPN does not protect you from any of the browser fingerprinting techniques mentioned in the question.

Comment: @user94444 In some circles, it's a moniker for child porn.